# How can I play a music such that it automatically replay it after its end?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

AVAudioPlayer *myExampleSound;

```
NSString *myExamplePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myaudiofile" ofType:@"caf"];

myExampleSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myExamplePath] error:NULL];

myExampleSound.delegate = self;

[myExampleSound play];
```

How can I play myExampleSound such that it automatically replay  after its end?
I am using the above code.

Anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVAudioPlayerDelegate has got a method

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

which is called after the sound has finished playing. You have to implement this method and then you are able to play your sound again.